# I need to fix file names on PO invoice generator when we upload file

Tags: coldfusion

```
    <cfif NOT DirectoryExists(ExpandPath(lv_upload_path))>
        <cfdirectory action="create"  directory="#ExpandPath(lv_upload_path)#">
    </cfif>

    <cfset lv_file_ext = listLast(FORM.filename_inv, ".") />

    <!--- replace special chars in comapny name except space, then replace space with underscore --->
    <cfset company_name = replaceSpecialChars(
        textString=FORM.company_name, 
        replaceTheseChars="33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,91,92,93,94,95,96,123,124,125,126"
    )>
    <cfset company_name = Replace( company_name, "#Chr(32)#", "_", "All" )>

    <cfset lv_file_name = company_name & "_Factura_" & replaceSpecialChars(FORM.in_supplier_inv) & "_" & DateFormat(FORM.in_when_inv, "dd.mm.yyyy") >
    <cfset lv_file_name_out = lv_file_name & "." & replaceSpecialChars(lv_file_ext)>

    <cffile action="upload" filefield="pickfiles_inv" destination="#ExpandPath(lv_upload_path & '/' & lv_file_name_out)#" nameconflict="MakeUnique">

    <cfset lv_document_name = CFFILE.serverfile />

    <cfset new_id = APPLICATION.po_management.f_savePOInvDocuments(
        p_po_inv_id=URL.id,
        p_supplier_number=FORM.in_supplier_inv,
        p_when_created=FORM.in_when_inv,
        p_amount=FORM.in_amount_inv,
        p_document_name=lv_document_name
```

Im new so if I make incorrect question, just help with how make it more good in future.

When upload a file give error back

Element FILENAME_INV is undefined in FORM.

Comment: If you want to write a good question (which in turn will help you receive more help), I would suggest you read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Start with dumping `form` scope to see whether the element is available?

Comment: thank you very much, I will

Answer (score 0):

Use the following line instead:

```
<cfset lv_file_ext = listLast(FORM.pickfiles_inv, ".") />
```